# Create connection pool in spring-data-cassandra 3.3.3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

After updating spring-boot to version 2.6.6, I had to update spring-data-cassandra to version 3.3.3, which doesn't contains PoolingOptions class. How I can set min and max pool size for local and remote connections?